# Add column to Azure SQL Database and display using Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, azure-mobile-services, azure-sql-database

I'm a newbie to dealing with Azure SQL Databases and Mobile Services. Does anyone know if it is possible to add a column to Azure SQL Database without having to go through the publish process in Visual Studio? When I download the mobile services project from Azure, I can publish the service and it will run with a new ToDoItems table. So I open up a SQL query in Visual Studio and add a column and add some random data to the new column 'Individual':

```
ALTER TABLE Numboo.TodoItems
ADD Individual nvarchar(max)

INSERT INTO Numboo.TodoItems (Text,Complete,Deleted,Individual)
VALUES ('90987834',1,0,'test data xxxxx')
```

But when I request the data from the table using mobile services, the data in the new column is null when I query the table

```
private MobileServiceCollection<TodoItem, TodoItem> demo;
private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> demoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();
demo = await demoTable.ToCollectionAsync();
//Individual is null
```

instead of "test data xxxxx" which I inserted via a sql query. Does anyone know if this is even possible to do it this way (add a column via script and access it using mobile services)? Or point me in the right direction or to an answer on SO if there is one? I'm not sure what I would be searching for. Thanks.

NB: I have updated the model/entity to reflect the new column in the database but that didn't make any difference:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to deploy your service with an updated model that matches the table schema/the model you want your API to expose. It's not enough to just change the client model.

Now, your question is specifically about publishing from VS, and although a deployment is required, you have other deployment options, including continuous deployment, which you can learn more about here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-store-code-source-control/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thought it was the case... Does re deployment of the service affect the data in the database? I think I was doing it wrong and re publishing the service with an updated model (i.e. I may need to add a new property/column) and it would clear the data but create the table with the new column. Is this correct? But if I update the table schema first and then republish the service to match the table schema it won't affect the data right?

Comment: Redeployment does not affect the data in the database.

Comment: dayzee, that behavior depends on the database initialization strategy you're using with EF. If you are using any of the Drop* initialization strategies in your service, you'll potentially have data deleted. 
I would recommend looking into EF Migrations to better understand how to handle changes/schema update scenarios.